# Laravel - Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, laravel, syntax-error

I'm using Laravel 9 and PHP 8.0. When I try to update a user, I get the following exception:

> SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL
> Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from
> character string.

I think the query being executed is internal to Laravel:

```
SELECT
  count(*) AS aggregate
FROM
  [ users ]
WHERE
  [ email ] = user_email
  AND [ id ] <> user_id
  AND [ deleted_at ] = NULL
```

user_email and user_id are the email and id of the user being updated.

I know that the issue here is because the query has incorrect syntax for SQL Server, it should be "[ deleted_at ] IS NULL" instead of "= NULL", but I don't know to fix it.

[QueryException Stack Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrwqh.jpg)

Comment: How do you trigger this? How do you specify that the value should be null?

Comment: The User model have "SoftDeletes" enabled, so Laravel automatically checks if the User being retrieved wasn't deleted with deleted_at = null, it works with mysql but doesn't with mssql because the syntax is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone. I was able to solve the issue thanks to Snapey at [Laracast forum](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/conversion-failed-when-converting-date-andor-time-from-character-string). The query was being executed because of the Laravel validation, but writing the validation like this generates the wrong query.

```
'email' => 'required|email|string|max:255|unique:users,email,'.$this->id.',id,deleted_at,null',
```

Changing it to this solves the issue:

```
'email' => [
    'required',
    'email',
    'string',
    'max:255',
    Rule::unique('users')
            ->ignore($this->id)
            ->where(fn (Builder $query) => $query->whereNull('deleted_at' ))],
```

I'm not sure if this is an issue with Laravel or if it's intended to work like this, but I think the simplified way should work as well and generate the right query.

Answer (score 2):

On the one hand, SQL Server does not allow filters of

```
something = null
```

to be used. On the other hand, you found a use-case when this is generated into the query.

This is unacceptable and not only due to syntax error, but also due to logical error. MySQL allows you to compare things with `null` and will return `null` to you.

Hence, you will need to contemplate on how you will resolve this. Possible solutions

## Fix the Laravel code

This will ensure that your code is different from Laravel's official code, which will get you into trouble if Laravel does not apply a similar fix, but you can reach out to Laravel's team and tell them about the problem, they may hopefully fix it.

## Create a DB proxy

You can write a CLI application that takes any command-line commands being sent to it, forwards it to SQL Server and when it gets the response, it sends it back to the issuer. You can implement such a proxy on your own or search for an existent part.

This proxy could then search for

```
= null
```

in any received query and replace it with `IS NULL`.

## Use a view

You could create a view for your users table for not deleted users and use this `view` when you are interested in not deleted users. Maybe you could have a BaseUser model class for common functionalities.

## Not using soft-delete

You can also avoid using soft-delete and implement the same logic yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Lajos. I did some tests inside the Laravel code, and I was able to fix the issue but that is far from ideal because I'm not sure what can break because of the changes that I made and, of course, as you said can cause issues in future updates. I will take a look at the DB proxy solution, but I never done that before. Using a view or removing soft-delete is not an option because is legacy code.

Comment: @RafaelOliveira you should complain to Laravel because they shouldn’t be generating `= null` syntax for SQL Server. I would call that a pretty serious bug.